# How to fix: 'Object is possible undefined' in react with typescript and mobx

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a mobx store (`AnimalStore`), which has an observable list of animals. And also, I have two components (ParentComponent and ChildComponent).

On the ParentComponent, I am displaying the total animals count, which I am getting from the observable list of mobx injected store (`animalStore.animals`). And on the ChildComponent, I am displaying all the animals, also from the observable list of mobx injected store (`animalStore.animals`).

On the ParentComponent, I am setting the props interface for the store as required. On the ChildComponent, I am setting the props for the store as optional.

But, I am getting a typescript error on the ChildComponent when I try to access `this.props.animalStore`:

> Object is possible undefined.

However, if I change the optional store props of ChildComponent as required, the error `Object is possible undefined.` goes away, but, on the ParentComponent I am getting error:

> Property of animalStore is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly'.

```
// ParentComponent.tsx

interface IProps {
    animalStore: AnimalStore
}

@inject('animalStore')
@observer
export default class ParentComponent extends React.Component<IProps> {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Total animals: {this.props.animalStore.animals.length}</Text>
                <SecondComponent/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}


// ChildComponent.tsx 

interface IProps {
    animalStore?: AnimalStore
}

@inject('animalStore')
@observer
export default class ChildComponent extends React.Component<IProps> {
    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
                {
                    this.props.animalStore.animals.map((el: string) => {
                        return <Text key={el}>{el}</Text>
                    })
                }
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}
```

I suppose I can fix this by `!` [Non-null assertion operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator), but is there any other way that can I fix this issue of typescript?

Answer (score 0):

### Root cause

Your `ChildComponent` defines a prop as a nullable. Notice the question mark:

```
interface IProps {
    animalStore?: AnimalStore
               ^
               |
               makes it nullable (AnimalStore | undefined)
}
```

### Solutions

You have a few options each of them can be a valid way to solve the problem depending on the broader context of your app.

**Option 1** -- don't declare it as nullable by removing the `?`

interface IProps {
    animalStore: AnimalStore;
}

**Option 2** -- enforce treating as non-falsy value by using [non-null assertion `!` operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator):

```
<ScrollView style={styles.container}>
  {
    this.props.animalStore!.animals.map((el: string) => {
                          ^
      return <Text key={el}>{el}</Text>
    })
  }
</ScrollView>
```

**Option 3** -- write defensive code which expects a possible null value of the store:

```
const {animalStore} = this.props;

<ScrollView style={styles.container}>
  {
    animalStore ?
      animalStore.animals.map((el: string) => {
        return <Text key={el}>{el}</Text>
      }) :
      <Text>Loading Animal Store...</Text>
  }
</ScrollView>
```